# Erro ao deletar FK

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela chamada:

solicitacaoemprestimo
codemprestimo, dataemprestimo, horaemprestimo

E outra tabela chamada:

emprestados, codemprestados, dataemprestimo, horaemprestimo, fk(solicitaremprestimo_codemprestimo)

e usei esse comando:

```
INSERT INTO emprestados (dataemprestimo,horaemprestimo, solicitacaoemprestimo_codemprestimo);

SELECT data emprestimo, horaemprestimo, codemprestimo FROM solicitacaoemprestimo WHERE codemprestimo = '13' 

DELETE FROM solicitacaoemprestimo WHERE codemprestimo = '13';
```

erro que esta dando:

> Error Code: 1451. Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`trabalhoclubedodvd`.`emprestados`, CONSTRAINT `fk_emprestados_solicitacaoemprestimo1` FOREIGN KEY (`solicitacaoemprestimo_codemprestimo`)

Só que, na hora que eu vou deletar na tabela solicitacaoemprestimo porque meu dvd foi alugado, ele não deixa, mas eu gostaria de deletar porque esse item não será mais usado por que o dvd já foi alugado... Se alguém puder me ajudar desde já eu agradeço...

Comment: Forneça mais dados , que tipo de erro ocorre , estrutura das tabelas fks , fks , triggers etc.

Comment: A coluna `solicitaremprestimo_codemprestimo` faz referência `a coluna `codemprestimo` da tabela `solicitacaoemprestimo`?

Comment: Esse erro:Error Code: 1451. Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`trabalhoclubedodvd`.`emprestados`, CONSTRAINT `fk_emprestados_solicitacaoemprestimo1` FOREIGN KEY (`solicitacaoemprestimo_codemprestimo`)

Comment: Sim faz referencia ...

Comment: @CarlosLeandroFerreiradeAlm conseguiu resolver essa pergunta?

Answer (score 2):

Isso é intencional — a ideia de criar uma chave estrangeira é impedir que uma coluna que faz referência a um ID em outra tabela armazene um valor inválido. Se a consulta que você quer fazer fosse permitida, uma linha teria o valor 13 para a coluna `solicitacaoemprestimo_codemprestimo` apesar de não existir nenhuma linha em `solicitacaoemprestimo` com `codemprestimo` igual a 13.

A motivação de apagar a linha correspondente em `solicitacaoemprestimo` é que a semântica que você tem em mente pra essa tabela é que ela só vai guardar solicitações *ativas*? Considere repensar o design do seu banco de dados e deixar todas as solicitações, pra sempre, nessa tabela — se você quiser filtrar só as solicitações que ainda não foram atendidas, você sempre pode fazer

```
…
WHERE codemprestimo NOT IN (SELECT solicitaremprestimo_codemprestimo FROM emprestados)
```

(mas aí seria importante você não mais repetir as colunas `dataemprestimo`, `horaemprestimo` na tabela `emprestados`)

Answer (score 0):

Complementando a resposta do [ctgPi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/67518/4087) você poderia criar um campo booleano para informar se a solicitação já foi alugada. Por exemplo:

```
ALTER TABLE solicitacaoemprestimo 
ADD alugado BOOLEAN
```

E no seu caso ficaria:

```
UPDATE solicitacaoemprestimo SET alugado = 1 WHERE codemprestimo = '13';
```

Ao invés do `DELETE`.

Comment: Essa solução funciona, mas eu não quis sugeri-la porque ela cria a possibilidade de você ter um registro em `emprestados` mas `alugado = 0` no registro correspondente `solicitacaoemprestimo` (ou vice-versa).