# Como apagar uma tabela que possui chaves estrangeiras no MYSQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql

Tentei usar o `DROP CASCADE` e `ALTER TABLE <nome_tabela> DROP FOREIGN KEY <chave_estrangeira>, DROP KEY <chave_estrangeira>` para deletar uma tabela com chaves estrangeiras no MYSQL, mas não dá certo.

```
CREATE TABLE forma_pagamento (
  cd_forma_pagamento INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  tipo_pagamento VARCHAR(30),
  CHECK (tipo_pagamento IN ('Pagamento á vista'))
);

-- Quero apagar a tebela pagamento, mas a chave da tabela forma_pagamento não permite
CREATE TABLE pagamento (
  cd_pagamento INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  cd_forma_pagamento INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (cd_forma_pagamento) REFERENCES forma_pagamento (cd_forma_pagamento)
);
```

Comment: Qual o erro está aparecendo? Pq vc deveria apagar primeiro as chaves estrangeiras e depois apaga a tabela `alter table pagamento drop foreign key cd_forma_pagamento`

Comment: ```Error Code: 1091. Can't DROP FOREIGN KEY `cd_forma_pagamento`; check that it exists
```

Comment: Tá dizendo que essa chave estrangeira não existe, qual erro dá quando você tenta apagar a tabela?

Comment: ```Error Code: 1451. Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails```

Comment: Talvez essa pergunta contenha a resposta que você procura https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67510/erro-ao-deletar-fk

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Erro ao deletar FK](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67510/erro-ao-deletar-fk)